# How do I add a link to a span of text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a link to a span of text using JavaScript below. Please could you help me with this issue.

```
<div id="features">
  <h2>Features</h2>
  <div id="emma2011_left">
    <h2>Image of the Day</h2>
    <div id="dImg">
      <div id="dailyimg" class="feature"></div>
      <div id="title" class="feature"></div>
      <div id="caption" class="feature"></div><br />
      <span id="span" class="feature"><a id="pidlink">Link to the object</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
...
link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", "http://example.com/index.aspx?objectid=" + oTodayImage.pid);
var span = document.createElement("span");
var txt = link.href;
var textNode = document.createTextNode(txt);
span.appendChild(textNode);
</script>
```

Comment: link isn't showing up, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Well that's because you never append the link to anything.

Comment: From your comments on the answers so far, it seems to me that you are looking for one-to-one tuition. That is not a good fit to this site's Q&A format. Perhaps try one of our chatrooms.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing one step. You added the textnode to the span instead of the link. Then you should've put the link into the span...

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.com");

var span = document.createElement("span");
var txt = link.href;
var textNode = document.createTextNode(txt);
link.appendChild(textNode);
span.appendChild(link);


//example of setting the link into a div on the page...
document.getElementById("div").appendChild(span);
```

Comment: i tried this code, but the hyperlink doesn't seem to show up.

Comment: you need to set `innerHTML ` property of the `link`

Comment: check out the edit. my original code was just to fix the creation of the span... you still need to put it somewhere...

Comment: @multiv123: you also need to append the `span` to something,for example: [`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(span);`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hHvVJ/).

Comment: @3nigma - nah... it's good... you're edit wasn't needed, though... this line [link.appendChild(textNode);] was handling what you talked about...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<a/>").attr({href:"http://google.com"}).html("google").appendTo("#span");
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wYdZb/1/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a text node you can also set the `innerHTML` of the link. And finally after you create this `span` you need to append it to some container, for now I have appended it to `body`.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2hZs9/)**

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
//here in the attribute value I have harded objectid=1 for testing
//replace it by your code to get the id and append it
link.setAttribute("href", "http://abc.org/index.aspx?objectid=1");
link.innerHTML = "Link to the object";
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.appendChild(link);
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: @multiv123 - Take a look at this solution.

Comment: i tried this, but the url itself doesn't attach to the link, weird

Comment: It works perfectly fine. You can take a look at the fiddle demo.

Comment: Am I supposed to change anything in the HTML?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2720/discussion-between-multiv123-and-shankarsangoli)

Comment: Do you want to replace the anchor in the span with id "span" or append a new anchor to it?

Comment: I want to append the new anchor to it with the innerHTML link text and url.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
  var _a, _div, _span;

  _span = document.createElement("span");
  _a = document.createElement("a");
  _div = (document.getElementsByTagName("div"))[0];

  _a.setAttribute("href", "http://abc.org/index.aspx?objectid=");
  _a.innerHTML = "Link to the object";

  _span.appendChild(_a);
  _div.appendChild(_span);
}).call(this);
```

1. to get the div element use some method;
2. must append span to the div element to show all elements.

example:http://jsfiddle.net/bz6bu/

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's [**append**](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
var href = "http://abc.org/index.aspx?objectid=" + oTodayImage.pid;
$('#span').append("<a href='" + href  + "'>test</a>")  ;
```